# Search engine relevancy

Tags: optimization, search-engine

I'm new to publishing websites but recently I bought a domain and hosting and created a website. The problem that I'm having is that when I search for my website it won't show up. Even when I search the whole address it says that its wrong although if I type it in the address bar it opens it. I have inserted meta keywords and description but as i said i am new to this and I was wondering what I have to do so that people can find it on search engines. The website is www.zaed.ro/flowers in case its important.

Answer (score 0):

Wow - I'm sorry to say it, but there are so, so many bugs on your web site. Your HTML source defines 2 different charsets, an incorrect language code, invalid tag parameters (it's "a title", not "a titlu"), etc.

But those aren't your problem with search engine findability. Your problem is time. You mention that you created the site recently. Search engines take a while to discover new sites, especially if they don't have a lot of inbound links from popular sites. You can submit your URL to Google, Yahoo, etc., but even that will take weeks before your site *may* get included in the search engines.